# EVAL in jQuery, this is the correct way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, eval, call

I need to call a jQuery function with EVAL (but I don't know how to do it), then I solve with this solution, but I don't think that this is the correct way...

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.customfunction = function (data) { alert( data ); }
</script>

<div id="eval_div"></div>
<form><input role="button" myFunction="customfunction"/></form>
<script>
$('[role=button]').click( function() {
var button = this;
$.post( "/action",
        $(form).serialize(),
        function (data) {
            $('#eval_div').html( "<script>" + $(button).attr('myFunction')  + "('" +  data   + "');</script>" );
        } );
});
</script>
```

customfunction is a general function for each form, each form has a different CUSTOMFUNCTION with different name, by this reason, the button has the name of the function.

Comment: This code works well.. my question is: Is it the correct way?

Comment: there is no correct way to use eval

Comment: @Claudiu - Even Crockford suggests `eval()` for JSON.

Comment: @Peter: really? `eval`ling to parse JSON could end up... doing anything.

Comment: @Claudiu - My bad. Don't know where I got that. At any rate, [here's some discussion of eval and JSON and why a parser is better](http://www.json.org/js.html)...... user439866 - I realize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to call the function... you can do it very simply:

```
function (data) {
    jQuery.fn[$(button).attr('myFunction')](data);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need eval in this case.  In JavaScript you can use dot notation or square brackets.  They mean the same thing.  Try this line.

```
$('#eval_div').html(jQuery.fn[$(button).attr('myFunction')](data));
```